# Progress Bar Not Stopping and hiding

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, uiactivityindicatorview

I built my apps with Xcode 8 and now I have updated to Xcode 9 and I was trying to my apps to swift 4, everything seems to be work unless the `UIActivityIndicator`, it doesn't stop even the WebView has been loaded. Googled but didn't find anything.

This is my code in VC

```
var timeBool: Bool!
var timer: Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView) {
    bar.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView) {
    bar.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: show your timer code

Comment: Check if webViewDidFinishLoad is called. You might be getting error and didReceiveError might be getting called instead.

Comment: dont have any timer code and i was using this in Xcode 8

Answer (score 0):

add below code snippet.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
        bar.stopAnimating()
    }
```

Also add breakpoints at each delegate methods. you will get where exactly the webview loading is finishing. May be load is failing and hence I have added this method.

Comment: check if you have connected your webview for delegates. 
also, check if any of the webview delegates are getting called?

Comment: I have a question here now.

which Bar you are using? its not UIProgressBar.

Comment: i am using Activity indicator view

Comment: code is perfectly OK. You need to look into xib/storyboard for connections. try to reset connections (remove and add indicator and web view). this may work.